# EclipseLink: call oracle StoredFunc with IN table type

Tags: oracle, eclipselink, stored-functions, oracle-type

I'm trying to call an oracle stored function using eclipselink 2.6.5, the storedfunction has an oracle type input.

This is te stored func:

```
create or replace function TEST_FUNC(PAR1 IN VARCHAR2, PAR2 IN MY_TYPE_T)
return varchar2 is 
 begin
  if PAR2 is null then
     return (PAR1 || ' 0');  
  else 
     return(PAR1 || ' ' || PAR2.count);    
  end if;
 end TEST_FUNC;
```

This is type declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MY_TYPE_T as table of MY_TYPE_R

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TYPE_R as object
(
  COD_P VARCHAR2(3),
  COD_S VARCHAR2(10)
)
```

This is the type mapping:

```
@Embeddable
@Struct(name="MY_TYPE_R", fields= {"COD_P", "COD_S"})
@PLSQLTable(
    name="MY_TYPE_R",
    compatibleType="MY_TYPE_T",
    nestedType="MY_TYPE_R"  
)
public class MyRecordType {

  @Column(name="COD_P")
  private String codP;

  @Column(name="COD_S")
  private String codS;

  //costructors, getter and setter...
}
```

This is the stored mapping:

```
@NamedPLSQLStoredFunctionQuery(
    name="testFunc",
    functionName="TEST_FUNC",
    returnParameter=@PLSQLParameter(
            name="RESULT",
            databaseType = "VARCHAR_TYPE"),
    parameters = {
            @PLSQLParameter(name = "firstParam", queryParameter="PAR1", databaseType = "VARCHAR_TYPE"),
            @PLSQLParameter(name = "secondParam", queryParameter="PAR2", databaseType = "MY_TYPE_T"),
    }
)
```

This is the call:

```
@Test
public void testFuncTest() {    
  List<MyRecordType> recTypeList = new ArrayList<MyRecordType>();
  MyRecordType rec = new MyRecordType();
  rec.setCodP("PValue");
  rec.setCodS("SValue");
  recTypeList.add(rec);

  Query query = getEM().createNamedQuery("testFunc");
  query.setParameter("firstParam", "FOO"); 
  query.setParameter("secondParam", recTypeList); 

  Assert.assertEquals("FOO 1", query.getSingleResult());
}
```

When I execute the test I get:
**PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_FUNC'**

Actually reading the documentation on @PLSQTable I'm a bit confused on the tree parameters:

- name
- compatibleType
- nestedType

Anyone has some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to use the OracleObject annotation to define your fields into an Oracle object. It's somewhat duplicate to Struct but required anyways.

```
@OracleObject(
        name = "MY_TYPE_R"
        , javaType = MyRecordType.class
        , fields = {
        @PLSQLParameter(name = "COD_P")
        ,@PLSQLParameter(name = "COD_S")
        }
)
```

For the PLSQLTable you want

```
@NamedPLSQLStoredFunctionQuery(
    name="testFunc",
    functionName="TEST_FUNC",
    returnParameter=@PLSQLParameter(
            name="RESULT",
            databaseType = "VARCHAR_TYPE"),
    parameters = {
            @PLSQLParameter(name = "PAR1", queryParameter="PAR1", databaseType = "VARCHAR_TYPE"),
            @PLSQLParameter(name = "PAR2", queryParameter="PAR2", databaseType = "MY_TYPE_T"),
    }
)
```

so the name needs to match what's in your function. The PLSQL table piece looks right, I believe the OracleObject part was your missing component and causing your error.